# Youtube-like video stabilization on Linux

Tags: video-editor, stabilisation

Does anyone knows a free video stabilization software for Linux (ubuntu, fedora or something else), whose result is like the Youtube Video Stabilization?

At this moment, to stabilize my video I need to upload my files on youtube and wait a lot until stabilization finishes and then download my files. One software for computer will be helpful, and save a lot of time.

Does anyone knows one?
Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

To stabilize your video you can use the [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) command line tool.

### The easy way: one pass using `deshake` filter

```
ffmpeg -i shaky-input.mp4 -vf deshake stabilized-output.mp4
```

The `deshake` filter has also some [optional settings](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deshake).

### The better way: two passes using `vidstab` filters

For better results you can try the two-step process using ffmpeg's `vidstabdetect` and `vidstabtransform` filters: (Thanks @Mulvya)

```
ffmpeg -i shaky-input.mp4 -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=5:show=1 dummy.mp4
```

This will output a `transforms.trf` that will be read by the second pass:

```
ffmpeg -i shaky-input.mp4 -vf vidstabtransform,unsharp=5:5:0.8:3:3:0.4 stabilized-output.mp4
```

The [vidstab filters documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vidstabdetect-1) explains all the configuration options.

Comment: There's also the vidstab filters.

Comment: I got this error: `No such filter: 'vidstabdetect'`. I guess on some distros (like Ubuntu) this filter isn't included by default.

Comment: libvidstab is external and GPL, so ffmpeg needs to be configured with `--enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl`

Comment: Tried multiple methods so far and the 2nd two-step process is the best quality and simplest so far. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) has [motion tracking](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/introduction.html), which can in turn be used to stabilize video.  Here is a YouTube tutorial showing how to load video footage into Blender's movie clip editor, setting a tracking point, solving the tracking equation, and then discusses considerations about how to balance the various factors between too much and too little stabilization.  The video tutorial is here:

Comment: Now do it on the command line

Comment: The original question did not ask for command line.